# How can I get a custom number of posts on the front page without views?

Tags: 7, nodes

I need to have 16 nodes on the front page. Drupal only allows 1-10, 15, 20, etc. I'm using views now but it breaks the AJAX of the rate module.

Answer (score 6):

The default front page article count is on the Site Information admin page @ **admin/config/system/site-information**. For some reason you can't select 16 as a value. If you have drush you can manually set the `default_nodes_main` value:

```
drush vset default_nodes_main 16
```

If you don't have drush you can set its value in the `variables` table.

Comment: It doesn't allow you to have 16 nodes, for whatever reason.

Comment: The problem want clear based on your question. I've updated the answer.

Comment: You could also add `$conf['default_nodes_main'] = 16;` to settings.php if Drush isn't an option

Answer (score 3):

Yet another option is available if you have the [Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable) module installed / enabled. That module is typically used/required for multilanguage sites using the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module, but of course you can also use the Variable module without using the i18n module.

When the [Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable) module is enabled, you should navigate to `/admin/config/system/variable`, and then select the tab "*Site Information*". There you'll find an option to specify "The maximum number of posts displayed on overview pages such as the front page."

Consider this option if (eg) you don't have Drush available (or can't use it for whatever reason), or as an alternative to modifying the settings.php file (2 possible alternatives mentioned in the prior answer/comments already).